# Filter RecyclerView with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am attempting to implement some type of filtering mechanism so that users can select a filter and it refreshes the underlying RecyclerView.  I would want to set it up so when a given filter is chosen, it fires of a specific Firebase Query. I have done some research but cannot find anyone that is implementing what I am looking for. I am a big fan of what Asana does with this overlay that can filter your tasks based on a certain state:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWkpG.jpg

Has anyone implemented something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i have implemented filter using firestore recyclerview

For implementing a filter mechanism using firebase try something like this:

Lets take asana for example :

here incomplete and completed tasks are two categories :

So in firebase what you could do is that create two seperate Collections say incomplete and another complete now both of the collections are seperate after that you can insert entries into that specific collection you want as filter.

And at runtime you should should specify that collection name from which all entries will be fetched.

[image: Take a look at my database which i have used to implement filter in my app]

Comment: Thanks! Thats a good idea about separate collections. How would you do the overlay they are doing? Is it a separate fragment?

Comment: No that's not a fragment it's a dialog you should take a look this library to create similar filter like asana.
https://github.com/orhanobut/dialogplus

Comment: Awesome! That's pretty neat. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Kevin please consider marking my answer correct if it helped i'll appreciate it!